# Appending tensors in Keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have a for loop in my keras model as follow:

```
 for t in range(Ty):
   ....
   ....
   ....

   out = Dense(num_dec_tokens, activation='softmax')(x)  # out.shape = (?, num_dec_tokens)
```

Is there a way that I can append the tensor 'out' for Ty times (for example using a lambda layer) without using a list, i.e., not using: outputs = [], then ... outputs.append(out)?

If so, is there a way that I can change the appended tensors into a shape of (?, Ty, num_dec_tokens) instead of (Ty, ?, num_dec_tokens)?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to [reshape](https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape) the outputs.

```
outputs = []

for i in range(Ty):
    out = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(x)
    outputs.append(out)

output = Concatenate()(outputs)
output = Reshape([Ty,3])(output)
```

Using [RepeatVector](https://keras.io/layers/core/#repeatvector) we can convert `(None, num_dec_tokens)` => `(None, Ty, num_dec_tokens)`

```
>>> dense = Dense(num_dec_tokens, activation="softmax")(x)
>>> out = RepeatVector(Ty)(dense)
```

In your case you will be learning Ty Dense layers, but not when using RepeatVector.

Comment: Thanks sathyz.  Your suggestion using 'Reshape' solved my problem.